# Smoothing 2D curves

Tags: matlab, geometry

I am trying to get a curve from the extracted boundary of the 3D mesh. I do the following to extract the boundary:

1- segment the 3d mesh into regions.

2- extract the boundary of each region

3- Transform 3D boundary into X-Y plane

4- segment the boundary

The following image shows the resulted boundary 
[image]

example of coordinate points

```
X            Y
0.24628 1.49185
0.26724 1.49886
0.26145 1.49709
1.09528 1.21106
0.24628 1.49185
0.26724 1.49886
0.26854 1.49843
0.26145 1.49709
0.27626 1.50001
0.28379 1.50117
0.28052 1.49995
0.29360 1.50299
0.30082 1.50435
0.31017 1.50628
0.31869 1.50840
0.31892 1.50806
0.31310 1.50721
0.32771 1.50982
0.32776 1.50974
0.32273 1.50908
0.33226 1.51077
0.33587 1.51100
0.33716 1.51156
0.35389 1.51406
0.34641 1.51295
0.35603 1.51355
0.36336 1.51487
0.35952 1.51450
0.37433 1.51553
0.37424 1.51531
0.36849 1.51516
0.37762 1.51612
0.39076 1.51885
0.38323 1.51721
0.39896 1.52063
0.39360 1.51947
0.40832 1.52167
0.39940 1.52079
0.40585 1.52160
0.41145 1.52172
0.41705 1.52184
0.44010 1.51656
0.43655 1.51850
0.43308 1.52038
0.42088 1.52166
0.42924 1.52165
0.45349 1.51545
0.44314 1.52105
0.44609 1.51949
0.44128 1.52194
0.44346 1.51851
0.43612 1.52077
0.43352 1.52161
0.45740 1.51952
0.45362 1.52152
0.45902 1.51864
0.45718 1.51776
0.44799 1.52223
0.45641 1.52190
0.45276 1.52210
0.46447 1.52093
0.46262 1.52249
0.45878 1.52173
0.47343 1.52308
0.46783 1.52254
0.48399 1.52349
0.51303 1.50714
0.51572 1.50538
0.52216 1.50146
0.47684 1.52328
0.51830 1.50370
0.56776 1.48180
0.49813 1.52070
0.50241 1.51843
0.50621 1.51529
0.50965 1.51151
0.49087 1.52312
0.49571 1.52185
0.51155 1.51048
0.51743 1.50665
0.51595 1.50950
0.52167 1.50431
0.52152 1.50752
0.60742 1.46625
0.60089 1.46988
0.59427 1.47344
0.58765 1.47702
0.52324 1.50821
0.53034 1.50552
0.53514 1.50419
0.54106 1.49936
0.54553 1.49744
0.55001 1.49553
0.55442 1.49351
0.57071 1.48188
0.57622 1.48183
0.58207 1.47688
0.55988 1.48783
0.56496 1.48702
0.55865 1.49114
0.56980 1.48577
0.65251 1.44821
0.64822 1.45052
0.63995 1.45493
0.62263 1.46408
0.63582 1.45711
0.63266 1.45877
0.62757 1.46143
0.66556 1.44139
0.65897 1.44477
0.64444 1.44978
0.65149 1.44698
0.61362 1.46728
0.62044 1.46407
0.60674 1.47039
0.67856 1.44030
0.67426 1.44258
1.08037 1.21854
1.08367 1.21654
1.08742 1.21428
1.09026 1.21255
0.64367 1.45327
0.67167 1.44238
0.80349 1.37805
0.83693 1.35981
0.70140 1.43402
0.69392 1.43810
0.69163 1.43933
1.07434 1.22838
0.83009 1.36350
0.68492 1.44079
1.07049 1.22964
1.07401 1.22600
1.07766 1.22044
1.08714 1.21527
1.09326 1.21187
1.09528 1.21106
0.75771 1.40927
0.75171 1.41250
0.82535 1.37218
0.81628 1.37709
0.82059 1.37477
0.78098 1.39647
0.79159 1.39056
0.78660 1.39332
0.76986 1.40262
0.76715 1.40411
0.76388 1.40590
0.75928 1.40841
0.75789 1.40840
0.74587 1.41221
0.73972 1.41662
0.84214 1.35978
0.83556 1.36343
0.84109 1.36350
0.82945 1.36790
0.82338 1.37248
0.81674 1.37601
0.80968 1.37878
0.78124 1.39398
0.77590 1.39922
0.78676 1.38842
0.79204 1.38798
0.79777 1.38182
0.80297 1.38219
0.70403 1.43426
0.70939 1.43395
0.69775 1.43844
0.70302 1.43797
0.72189 1.42546
0.72809 1.42115
0.73366 1.42121
0.71565 1.42973
1.02362 1.26324
1.02790 1.25927
1.03297 1.25290
1.03732 1.25075
1.03167 1.25609
1.03570 1.25336
1.07091 1.23630
1.07433 1.23212
1.04194 1.24911
1.04686 1.24801
1.05225 1.24701
0.89862 1.33866
0.88048 1.34835
0.87569 1.35094
0.88905 1.34370
0.88686 1.34488
0.88223 1.34740
0.87377 1.35197
0.99367 1.28666
1.00647 1.27936
0.74504 1.41621
0.88074 1.34740
0.87411 1.35094
0.88826 1.33991
0.88732 1.34374
0.84792 1.36006
0.85374 1.36074
0.86725 1.35408
0.86039 1.35723
1.01659 1.26882
1.02050 1.26590
1.01152 1.27520
1.01537 1.27215
1.05677 1.24591
1.06151 1.24448
1.06584 1.24230
1.06970 1.23928
0.92078 1.33298
0.91777 1.33456
0.91618 1.33539
0.91196 1.33758
0.90920 1.33893
0.97498 1.30304
0.91081 1.33406
0.90963 1.33746
0.90193 1.33908
0.89438 1.34089
0.89976 1.34070
0.99758 1.28554
1.00174 1.28305
0.97934 1.29917
0.99152 1.29012
0.98521 1.29424
0.99577 1.28780
0.93860 1.32947
0.95180 1.32233
0.94649 1.32523
0.95703 1.31941
0.95579 1.32010
0.96171 1.31675
0.94571 1.32566
0.94042 1.32850
0.93912 1.32861
0.93204 1.33136
0.92474 1.33369
0.91717 1.33555
0.92264 1.33544
0.91508 1.33731
0.96647 1.31145
0.97034 1.30845
0.97396 1.30499
0.95091 1.32440
0.95694 1.31976
0.96123 1.31751
0.95508 1.32193
```

Comment: The data before smoothing has a strange order, the curve doesn't follow the contour. Why is this? It looks like the points are generated independently?

Comment: Thanks Cris for replying. The point initially extracted from 3d mesh then I apply a transformation matrix to get x-y point. what is the best way to order the points?

Comment: you have segments with different colors identified, it means you can smooth them individually. I would recommend smoothing them each along their longuest dimension. So for your blue segment, I would swap `[x,y]`=>`[y,x]` then smooth it.

Comment: I try to swap x,y but its not works.

Comment: Hoki’s suggestion is really good. Please show your code when you say “it does not work”. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: One way to smooth such curves is to transform them in polar coordinates, sort them by angle and smooth them. However this won't work well with paths that are too convoluted. Can you post the x-y coordinates of your example? Otherwise, could you directly smooth your 3D surface? It might be easier!

Comment: @Zep I add the coordinate points of one boundary segment. Thanks

Comment: It seems like you edited the question out of your post. Please edit it back in!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and compare the inputs to yours.

```
% Generate Noisy coordinates of a circle
h = viscircles([0,0],100);
x_noisy = h.Children(1).XData + randn(1,182);
y_noisy = h.Children(1).YData + randn(1,182);

% Smooth the coordinates
x_smooth = smoothdata(x_noisy,'gaussian',20);
y_smooth = smoothdata(y_noisy,'gaussian',20);

% Display the results 
plot(x_noisy, y_noisy)
hold on
plot(x_smooth, y_smooth)
hold off
axis image
legend('Noisy', 'Smoothed')
```

Comment: This is likely not going to work, as the data points that OP has are not ordered along the line.

Comment: Then the problem isn't about smoothing but how he acquired the coordinates.

Comment: OP should try not to use sort after the transformation.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. As Cris comment, the problem is with the points order as it is extracted from 3D mesh then transformed into 2D points. How can I get the best curve that fits these points?

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you showed the code that you used for extracting the boundary.

Comment: I use region growing then merging to segment the surface into different regions then I use the following to extract the boundary  (boundary = intersect(Region1 , Region2);)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what I meant in my comment. The idea is to sort your points using polar coordinates, smooth the coordinates independently and transform back to cartesian coordinates. This will not work well if there are loops in your curves!

```
% Transform in polar coordinates
[theta , rho] = cart2pol(x,y);

% Sort data by angle
data = sortrows([theta , rho]);
theta = data(:,1);
rho = data(:,2);

% Smooth coordinates
theta = smooth(theta);
rho = smooth(rho , 10); % More aggressive smoothing for rho. You might
                        % have to adapt the type of smoothing to the 
                        % actual data of course.

% Transform back in cartesian coordinates
[X , Y] = pol2cart(theta , rho);

% Plot original and smooth result
plot(x,y,'b.')
hold on;
plot(X,Y , 'r-')
```